# Cloudera manager can not recognize "Invalid region ID "ap-southeast-2" region on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudera-manager

I have installed cloudera manager on the AWS EC2 instance successfully.

Now i am able to login using

```
public-ip:7180
```

After selecting edition i am getting following error in installation.

```
Server Error

A server error has occurred. Send the following information to Cloudera.

Path: http://public-ip:7180/cmf/cloud-express-wizard/specs

Version: Cloudera Enterprise Data Hub Trial 5.0.0-beta-2 (#119 built by jenkins on 20140209-0301 git: 8acd3c5559ccf82bf374d49bbf00bce58dee286e)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Invalid region ID "ap-southeast-2".
at CloudConstants.java line 183
in com.cloudera.server.cmf.cloud.CloudConstants$Region byId() 


Stack Trace:

    CloudConstants.java line 183
    in com.cloudera.server.cmf.cloud.CloudConstants$Region byId()
    EC2MetadataFetcher.java line 48
    in com.cloudera.server.web.cmf.cloud.EC2MetadataFetcher getCMRegion()
    CloudHostsWizardControllerBase.java line 81
    in com.cloudera.server.web.cmf.cloud.CloudHostsWizardControllerBase wizardSpecs()
    <generated> line -1
    in com.cloudera.server.web.cmf.cloud.CloudHostsWizardControllerBase$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3874b0fc invoke()
    MethodProxy.java line 191
    in net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy invoke()
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot for answer then found the actual reason behind the error.

The error was like cloudera can not recogonize the **region id** beacuse

your **AWS EC2** running instances are in wrong region i.e **ap-southeast-2**. You need to change to different in my case that was **US-West Zone.**
You can change the regions if you have access and authorization for changing regions for instances

Read the given link for different regions

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html
```